# HTML nav menu background color

Tags: html, css

I am editing a Bootstrap template and I am trying to change the color of the navigation menu at the top.

I have this section of the code here:

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://home.channeliser.com/Content/WebContent/images/logo1.png" alt="Channeliser" height="40" width="100"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">How it works</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried using the navbarr class name in the CSS file to change the background but it did not work. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: If you're using a modern browser, you should be able to right-click your `nav.navbar`, choose Inspect Element or its equivalent, and then from the developer tools determine which CSS property is dictating the background colour. I would expect it to be using a `!important` or perhaps be a stricter condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Without seeing all the CSS for the page it is impossible to know if that will work, but absent any other CSS it should do the job.

Comment: Then I need more information to help you.  Please include the rest of your code for the page.

Comment: Since my answer was false. I tried this guys method and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

its work for me on **Bootstrap 4**

solve with remove the **bg-light** class
and add your own class

*Example*

**your code :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">

</nav>
```

**change to :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light your-bg-navbar fixed-top">
   //navbar item
</nav>
```

remove **bg-light** and **add your own CSS**

**Add CSS :**

```
.your-bg-navbar {
    background-color: rgba(35,35,35,0);
}
```

**rgba is for transparant** color you can change solid

background-color: red or #rgbcolor

hope this work your for you to.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.bg-light` has a background colour with an `!important` so will override anything you try unless you also use `!important`:

```
.navbar {
background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from experience, bootstrap css will all take superiority over your custom css except your add the !important tag at the end of the property. So the answer to your question is

```
.navbar {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Alternatively,
You can add a custom css file  replacing the bg-light class with you own custom class.